# Style.css not loading

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, my style.css isn't loading.
This is the head section off my html code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Caculator</title>
    <style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>
</head>
```

This is the first part off my style.css:

```
button   {
    font-size: 50pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: grey;
    border-radius: 7pt;
    border: 1pt solid grey;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 54pt;
    height: 70pt;
    margin: 2pt;
}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Edit: all my files are in the same folder, no subfolders

Comment: Did you try to add rel="stylesheet" in <style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style> ?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul I tried, it's not working

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">` instead of `<style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>`.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

instead of 
  the link tag currently in yout html

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheet import method  try.

Sample: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```